# jQuery resize window on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'v placed a jquery slider in a Bootstrap tab but the tab does not function unless the window is resized. I'm guessing this is because it's being created in an empty container instead of being fired once the container exists.

I've tried triggering a window resize event upon clicking the tab:

```
    $('#myTab a[href="#slider"]').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show');
      jQuery(window).trigger('resize');
    $('.swiper-container').css('height','100%').css('width','100%');
    })
```

But it didn't work.

JS Fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/kn7ywxef/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Swiper function once slider tab is displayed..

```
    var isSliderActive = false;

    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        if($(this).attr('href') == "#slider"){ 
            if(isSliderActive === false){ //If slider is not active 
                var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
                    pagination: '.pagination',
                    paginationClickable: true
                });
            }
            isSliderActive = true;
       }    
    });
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kn7ywxef/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Expand and collscape div:

```
var open = false;
$('#SlideButton').click(function () {
    if (open === false) {
        $('#SlideContent').animate({ height: '650px' }, 600);
        $('#SlideContent').css('display', 'block');
        $(this).css('background-position', 'bottom left');
        open = true;
    }
    else {
        $('#SlideContent').animate({ height: '0' }, 600, function () {
            $('#SlideContent').css('display', 'none');
        });
        $(this).css('background-position', 'top left');
        open = false;
    }
});
```